# Get local coords from global coords

Tags: 2d, mathematics, coordinates

I need to get local coords from global coords. I did not find ready-made examples.

[image]

Please help me how to do it on the example image. Thank you!

### UPDATED:

Here's the method in the java, created thanks to your help! It works for me :) Thank you!

```
public static double[] getLocalFromGlobal(int pointX, int pointY, int localX, int localY, float angle) {
    float px = pointX - localX;
    float py = pointY - localY;

    double cos = Math.cos((Math.PI / 180) * angle);
    double sin = Math.sin((Math.PI / 180) * angle);

    double finalX = (px * cos) + (py * sin);
    double finalY = -(px * sin) + (py * cos);
    return new double[]{finalX, finalY};
}
```

Comment: Use a *Homogenous Transformation Matrix* with R = a CW rotation by 45 degrees and T = a translation by (40,20). If you need the inverse, use the inverses.

Comment: More here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/103654/rotate-coordinates-back-after-rotating-game-context-geometry/105331#105331

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The point P to be transformed is, in homogeneous coordinates:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
50 \\
40 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The homogeneous transformation matrix M is (using \$cos(\frac{\pi}{4}\$) = sin(\$\frac{\pi}{4}) = 0.7071)\$:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 0.7071 &0.7071  &-42.426 \\
-0.7071 &0.7071  &14.142 \\
 0      &0       & 1     \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

noting that \$(40+20) * 0.7071 = 42.426\$ and \$(40-20) * 0.7071 = 14.142\$ and using the identity proved in my answer [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/103654/rotate-coordinates-back-after-rotating-game-context-geometry/105331#105331)

Applying M to P with matrix multiplication yields

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
     35.35 &+ &28.28 &- &42.42 \\
    -35.35 &+ &28.28 &+ &14.14 \\
      0    &+ &0     &+ &1    \\
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
21.21 \\
7.07  \\
 1    \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Note that [normal vectors, such as for position and velocity, are *contra-variant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_of_vectors); this means that for a transformation T of the basis vectors, the components transform by the inverse transformation, T*. Only *dual vectors* such as gradient are co-variant, with their components transforming by T.